# Pygame Flip Image Problem How To Fix Pygame?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to flip this bunny if I am going left it should flip my bunny left and load the same animation  but I am getting this error

```
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 52, in draw
    self.playa = pygame.transform.flip(self.playa,True,True)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

I just want it to flip the same animation and do the same thing

```
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            self.playa = pygame.transform.flip(self.playa,True,True)
            window.blit(self.playa[self.so_index],self.rect) 
            self.so_index += 1
            if self.so_index == len(self.playa):
                self.so_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.playa[self.to_index],self.rect) 
            self.to_index += 1
            if self.to_index == len(self.playa):
                self.to_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "standing":
                window.blit(self.standing,self.rect)
        if self.direction == "Jump":
            window.blit(self.jump,self.rect)
```

my full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")

bunnystand = pygame.image.load("bunny2_stand.png")

jump  = pygame.image.load("bunny2_jump.png")
playa = [pygame.image.load("bunny2_walk2.png"),
         pygame.image.load("bunny2_walk2.png"),

         ]

# player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color 
        self.d_indesx = 0
        self.s_index = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.standing = "standing"
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.speed = 5
        self.jump  = pygame.image.load("bunny2_jump.png")
        self.standing = pygame.image.load("bunny2_stand.png")
        self.playa = [
         pygame.image.load("bunny2_walk2.png"),
         pygame.image.load("bunny2_walk2.png")
         ]
        self.fall = 0
        self.so_index = 0
        self.do_index = 0
        self.to_index = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.direction = "Jump"
        self.direction = "standing"
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            self.playa = pygame.transform.flip(self.playa,True,True)
            window.blit(self.playa[self.so_index],self.rect) 
            self.so_index += 1
            if self.so_index == len(self.playa):
                self.so_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.playa[self.to_index],self.rect) 
            self.to_index += 1
            if self.to_index == len(self.playa):
                self.to_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "standing":
                window.blit(self.standing,self.rect)
        if self.direction == "Jump":
            window.blit(self.jump,self.rect)





# platforms
class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,plat.get_width(), plat.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.plat,(self.plat.get_width()//2,self.plat.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.plat,self.rect)

# Coins
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,coinss.get_width(), coinss.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.coinss,(self.coinss.get_width()//2,self.coinss.get_height()//2))
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.coinss,self.rect)


# Floor
class floor:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
score = 0
text = font.render('Gold  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)


# fps
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (63, 190, 22)
Blue = (22, 190, 175)
white = (240, 240, 240)

# define the enemy player coin classes
playerman = player(40,390,30,30, Blue)
enemy1 = platform(150,390,190,10, Green)
enemy2 = platform(300,310,190,10, Green)
enemy3 = platform(80,260,190,10, Green)
enemy4 = platform(250,180,190,10, Green)
enemy5 = platform(490,120,190,10, Green)
enemy6 = platform(-50,100,190,10, Green)
enemy7 = platform(180,50,190,10, Green)
platforms = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,enemy5,enemy6,enemy7]

# coin class
coin1 = coin(180,320,50,50, Green)
coin2 = coin(350,250,50,50, Green)
coin3 = coin(150,200,50,50, Green)


Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3]

# floor class
floor1 = floor(-1000,490,9999,50, white)
flories = [floor1]

#main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y += playerman.speed


    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y -= playerman.fall



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    playerman.direction = "standing"

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed






    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False
        collide = False
        for platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.right
            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()  
                    textRect.center = (100, 40)    



        for floor in flories:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = floor.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.right




            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.direction = "Jump"
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0


    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False

    window.fill((74, 107, 104))
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for platform in platforms:
        platform.draw()
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()
    playerman.draw()
    for floor in flories:
        floor.draw()



    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: While flipping isn't too slow (as opposed to image rotation), the code should probably create all the flipped versions before the main-loop starts.  Maybe into separate lists `self.playa_left` and `self.playa_right`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@The Big Kahuna identified the specific problem in your code, i.e. that you are trying to call `pygame.transform.flip()` on a list of images rather than on an image. I am going to comment on another problem with the way you are handling this in your code (assuming that you fix that issue).

Every time you call your players draw() method, you are checking if you are going left and if so you `pygame.transform.flip()` image or group of images. That means you are going through the overhead of flipping the images every time, which makes no sense. You should flip them once at the beginning in `__init__()` when you load the images. Then you have a right set of images and a left set of images and in the players draw() you just select from one or the other to blit, you don't suffer the overhead of doing the flip each time.

More generally if possible you should try to create the various images that you are going to need (be they scaled, flipped, rotated, or whatever other transformations required) only once and then use the pre-created images during the running of the game.

Comment: Not sure that I should be getting credit for the answer here. @The Big Kahuna described your specific bug that you were enquiring about (and I noted/referenced his answer in mine). I was just trying to point out a larger issue that you should also resolve.

Answer (score 2):

the `self.playa` is a list of images. it has 2 images called 'bunny2_walk2.png' and the other is the same. Did you want one of them to be flipped? or are you going to add more images to the animation, or was is a typo?.

The problem is that once again, the list isnt a surface, it is a list, its like trying to photocopy a pile of paper on a printer, and putting the whole stack of paper in at the same time, it just doesnt work, you need to do it one at a time, the stack of paper isnt a single paper, it is a list of paper, so

```
self.playa[self.so_index] = pygame.transform.flip(self.playa[self.so_index],True,True)
```

that will flip the image in the list, the problem is, it will keep flipping it every frame, so one frame it will be flipped, then the next it wont, then the next it will etc. so if you want to use the animation for both directions, do this

```
img = pygame.transform.flip(self.playa[self.so_index],True,True)
window.blit(img,self.rect)
```

this will flip the image once, and not affect the image in the animation. you could also create a new list that is flipped and then just use that.

---

The image is upside down because you flipped it horizontally and vertically, so change it to

```
pygame.transform.flip(self.playa[self.so_index],True,False) #True for x, False for y
```

To slow it down, you need to change the `self.so_index` less. There are 2 ways to do this,

1) wait for certain amount of time
2) wait for certain amount of frames

waiting for time is better because different computers may run your game with different fps, so it will be slower/faster, while time will be the same for all computers

To do this, we need to get the time, `pygame.time.get_ticks()` does, this, so create `self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()`. Lets also create a variable to know how long each image so stay for. `self.anim_fps = 100`. this is in milliseconds so 100 is 0.1 seconds

i think it will be easier to make a new function for this

```
def Get_image(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks() #get the current time
    if now - self.start_time > self.anim_fps: #if the difference in time is greater then self.anim_pfs
        self.so_index += 1 #get next frame
        self.start_time = now
        if self.so_index == len(self.playa):
            self.so_index = 0
    return self.playa[self.so_index]
```

Now in draw

```
def draw(self):
    self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
    if self.direction == "left":
        img = pygame.transform.flip(self.Get_image(),True,False)
        window.blit(img,self.rect) 
    elif self.direction == "right":
        window.blit(self.Get_image(),self.rect) 
    elif self.direction == "standing":
            window.blit(self.standing,self.rect)
    if self.direction == "Jump":
        window.blit(self.jump,self.rect)
```

Comment: the image flips and works good but its https://gyazo.com/24cb72a3cfc1e63d6b24dc3f7d48b41d upsight down for left is there way to fix that? also how do I slow the image so the frames run slower instead of going fast as you can see in the video

Comment: @HabibIsmail Also you should not be doing the flip in the draw. You should create a left and right set of images in the __init__() and chose between them in the draw, not suffer the overhead of doing the flip in the draw every time.

Comment: @HabibIsmail You marked my answer as 'the answer'. I am not sure that I should be getting credit for the answer for this. `@The Big Kahuna described the specific bug that you were enquiring about here (and I specifically noted/referenced his answer in mine). I was just trying to point out a larger issue that you should also resolve.

Comment: I am confused by a comment in your answer 'different computers may run your game with different fps'.The OP has set his FPS = 60, which means that pygame will limit the frame rate and not allow the frames to be less that 1/60th of a second. Why would different computers run at different fps? Or are you implying that on some systems the code may be too slow and the per frame computation would take longer than 1/60th of a second, so the game cannot keep up and it would run slower than 60 FPS on slow systems (not that some might run it faster)?

Comment: @GlennMackintosh Yes, i was talking about running slower, not necessarily on this program, but generally speaking, you want to account for that

Comment: @GlennMackintosh and yes, i do agree with flipping the images in `__init__`. i did mention it but forgot about it